# How to get Login / username using Azure AD Graph API for current user

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Can anyone tell me what to write in the query to get the login user, AD username?
! NOT GivenName, FamilyName, displayname----
I need domain**me.username**, well I have the domain, so just the username.
This works perfectly, to retrieve the user's AD groups, so what should I change to get username.

```
public async Task<List<Groups>> GetAdGroups(string authority, string resource, string clientId, string returnUri)
    {
        JObject jResult = null;
        AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
        var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority);
        if (authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().Any())
        {
            authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authContext.TokenCache.ReadItems().First().Authority);
        }
        var platformParams = new PlatformParameters((Activity)Forms.Context);
        authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource, clientId, new Uri(returnUri), platformParams);
        var uri = new Uri(returnUri);
        string graphRequest = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}/{1}/users/{2}/memberOf?api-version=1.5", ServiceConstants.graphResourceUri, ServiceConstants.tenant, authResult.UserInfo.UniqueId);
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, graphRequest);
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", authResult.AccessToken);

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        List<Groups> memberOf = new List<Groups>();
        string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        jResult = JObject.Parse(content);

        if (jResult["odata.error"] != null)
        {
            memberOf.Add(new Groups { id = "Error", displayName = (string)jResult["odata.error"]["message"]["value"] });
            return memberOf;
        }
        if (jResult["value"] == null)
        {
            memberOf.Add(new Groups { id = "Error", displayName = "Unknown Error." });
            return memberOf;
        }
        foreach (JObject result in jResult["value"])
        {
            memberOf.Add(
                new Groups
                {
                    id = (string)result["objectId"],
                    displayName = (string)result["displayName"]
                });
        }
        return memberOf;
    }
```

Hope that someone can help. Best regards, Christian.

Comment: You could also decode the authContext (check https://jwt.io), since that will include the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the login name for Azure AD account, we can get the **userPrincipalName** from user object. Below is the description about this property from [Entity and complex type reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/entity-and-complex-type-reference#user-entity).

*The UPN is an Internet-style login name for the user based on the Internet standard RFC 822. By convention, this should map to the user's email name. The general format is "alias@domain". For work or school accounts, the domain must be present in the tenant's collection of verified domains. This property is required when a work or school account is created; it is optional for local accounts.*

And here is the code using Azure Graph client to get this property for your reference:

```
//client is the instance of ActiveDirectoryClient
client.Me.ExecuteAsync().Result.UserPrincipalName
```

And if you were call the Azure Graph REST directly, you can refer the request below:

```
GET: https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6
```

Comment: Thank you, I will then just split it by @ and everything is ok

Comment: If the userType is Guest, then the UserPrincipalName will be xxx_xxx.com#EXT#@xxx.xxx.com, just a heads-up for anyone who comes to this answer.